# The induced functor in the definition of Deligne's tensor product is exact?

Tags: ct.category-theory

In the sec 1.11. "Delignes' tensor product of locally finite abelian categories" of the book "Tensor Categories" of EGNO, the deligne's tensor 
product $C \boxtimes D$ of two k-linear locally finite abelian categories $C$ ad $D$ is defined by the universal property:
$$
\matrix{
C \times D & \xrightarrow{\boxtimes} & C \boxtimes D\\
& F \searrow & \downarrow{ \exists ! G} \\
& & A
}
$$
i.e., $\boxtimes: C \times D \rightarrow C \boxtimes D$ is a bilinear bifuntor which is right exact in both variables and is such that
for any right exact bilinear bifunctor $F: C \times D \rightarrow A$, where $A$ is k-linear locally finite abelian category, there exists a unique right exact $k$-linear functor $G: C \boxtimes D \rightarrow A$ such that
$$
G \circ \boxtimes = F.
$$

It is also claimed that if $F$ is exact, then $G$ is also exact. I would like to know how to prove this fact? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Minor correction: it's claimed that if $F$ is exact _in each variable_, then $G$ is also exact. $F$ will rarely be exact -- it rarely preserves $\oplus$ (since it preserves $\oplus$ in each variable). But I agree that $F$ preserves monos in each variable if and only $F$ preserves monos.

Comment: $F$ is bilinear, so it preserves $\oplus$. I hope to find a proof shows that $F$ preserves monos in each variable implies that $G$ preserves monos.

Comment: $F$ being bilinear does not imply that $F$ preserves $\oplus$. The decategorified version of this statement is the fact that a bilinear function between vector spaces is very rarely a linear function.